# Please create a [pyramid] tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I am new on Code Review, so I don't have the privilege to create a tag.  Can one of you create it for me?

Tag name: [pyramid](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyramid) or [pyramid-framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyramid-framework)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should post the rest of the question with a line ending as a request to create/retag it with [pyramid](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyramid). Users with enough reps. will create it for you then.